# messed up output with installation of oh-my-zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to install oh-my-zsh on my terminal. However, I do not have the privilege to set the default sh to zsh instead of bash. So this command failed:

```
chsh -s $(grep /zsh$ /etc/shells | tail -1)
```

So I thought I can just put `exec zsh` in .bashrc(Ubuntu) to switch to zsh every time terminal is started but I see output like the picture below.

[Here is the output I see in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6HwO.png)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, zsh version is 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is with my encoding: I am using ISO-8859-1 but if I switch to UTF-8 then the output is fine